# How can I modify more than one array's object at the same time?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this array:

```
array = ["the","quick","brown","fox"]

array[0,2] = "substitute"
puts array
```

I thought I would get: "substitute quick substitute fox"

But instead I got "substitute brown fox"

I can tell it's a rookie mistake, I thought I could replace more than one object in an array, by writing array[0,2] = x, but it seems not, so, How can I replace more than one object in an array in the same line?

Comment: When you need something on one line - make a method of it. `arr.replace_elements([0, 2], 'substitute')`

Comment: If you understood that you used `Array#[i, j]` in a wrong way, then don't write that. It does not make your question any clearer. It is just confusing, and is extra noise. Just ask what you want.

Comment: You need to know what []= operator does first... it doesn't take various length parameters. It is: `arr[start, length] `

Answer (score 4):

```
[0,2].each { |i| array[i] = "substitute" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ranges for that.

```
(0...array.length).step(2).each { |i| array[i] = "substitute" }
```

Comment: This is definitely some strange assumption about what OP wants :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ah :-) I have realized it now.